# Why does Kubernetes allow global read/write in kubelet directory?

Tags: security, kubernetes

I installed Kubernetes 1.13.1 cluster using `kubeadm`, docker `17.12.1-ce` and flannel networking

However, I found that Kubernetes master server has many empty files with permission 666 which allows any user can read/write by command:

```
$ find /var/lib -perm 666
```

The following results shows that Kubernetes components `kube-controller-manager`, `kube-scheduler`, `etcd`, `kube-apiserver`, `kube-proxy`, `coredns`, `install-cni` and `kube-flannel` created those insecure files.

```
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/d4ff37ee76fe761a28f11175fd1c384e/containers/kube-controller-manager/67675b22
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/d4ff37ee76fe761a28f11175fd1c384e/containers/kube-controller-manager/2472b441
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/d4ff37ee76fe761a28f11175fd1c384e/containers/kube-controller-manager/4bd17709
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/d4ff37ee76fe761a28f11175fd1c384e/containers/kube-controller-manager/ed3b53cd
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/d4ff37ee76fe761a28f11175fd1c384e/containers/kube-controller-manager/db4af185
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/d4ff37ee76fe761a28f11175fd1c384e/containers/kube-controller-manager/043af2e4
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/d4ff37ee76fe761a28f11175fd1c384e/containers/kube-controller-manager/c53c15c7
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/d4ff37ee76fe761a28f11175fd1c384e/containers/kube-controller-manager/a16fefca
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/44b569a35761491825f4e7253fbf0543/containers/kube-scheduler/1d5bf9d8
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/44b569a35761491825f4e7253fbf0543/containers/kube-scheduler/c94fa723
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/44b569a35761491825f4e7253fbf0543/containers/kube-scheduler/4bd7ff3b
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/44b569a35761491825f4e7253fbf0543/containers/kube-scheduler/16991a34
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/44b569a35761491825f4e7253fbf0543/containers/kube-scheduler/cc39443a
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/44b569a35761491825f4e7253fbf0543/containers/kube-scheduler/e6e4aace
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/44b569a35761491825f4e7253fbf0543/containers/kube-scheduler/81a73a2d
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4f58ccda5ae6e0c130245af30581f553/containers/etcd/aa52c49d
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4f58ccda5ae6e0c130245af30581f553/containers/etcd/4ab06094
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4f58ccda5ae6e0c130245af30581f553/containers/etcd/48d77ff1
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4f58ccda5ae6e0c130245af30581f553/containers/etcd/8a69b2a8
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4f58ccda5ae6e0c130245af30581f553/containers/etcd/2d3110c6
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4f58ccda5ae6e0c130245af30581f553/containers/etcd/1050c0c2
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4f58ccda5ae6e0c130245af30581f553/containers/etcd/3c9b35d2
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4f58ccda5ae6e0c130245af30581f553/containers/etcd/585456e6
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/431d2fd1385de8d92297e09b707498e8/containers/kube-apiserver/8be88549
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/431d2fd1385de8d92297e09b707498e8/containers/kube-apiserver/cfb428fd
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/431d2fd1385de8d92297e09b707498e8/containers/kube-apiserver/013626b1
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/431d2fd1385de8d92297e09b707498e8/containers/kube-apiserver/7e786acf
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/431d2fd1385de8d92297e09b707498e8/containers/kube-apiserver/9421eba8
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/431d2fd1385de8d92297e09b707498e8/containers/kube-apiserver/7ed5b175
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/431d2fd1385de8d92297e09b707498e8/containers/kube-apiserver/6fc2a524
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/431d2fd1385de8d92297e09b707498e8/containers/kube-apiserver/dca6882b
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/205f8dce-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-proxy/914ac6c3
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/205f8dce-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-proxy/3c44eff3
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/205f8dce-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-proxy/a85f6e51
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/205f8dce-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-proxy/c4463b68
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/205f8dce-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-proxy/34e5f60f
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/205f8dce-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-proxy/e0376b53
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/205f8dce-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-proxy/b3826292
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/205f8dce-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-proxy/aecca296
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076242e-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/117caf5a
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076242e-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/438a9268
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076242e-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/335b2b55
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076242e-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/6cfbeba3
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076242e-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/b8af2455
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076242e-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/cc246570
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076242e-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/036e6102
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076f7b0-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/59e51c33
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076f7b0-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/fc15d13f
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076f7b0-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/68e17599
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076f7b0-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/ee907d2f
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076f7b0-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/96253eba
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076f7b0-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/38268733
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076f7b0-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/57319601
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/2076f7b0-31b6-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/coredns/9d2cc8d4
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/b480c6a8
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/13b9e8b2
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/caf80049
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/e1956197
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/6f7cf72c
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/ae3a7534
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/cfde7073
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/4c5f4031
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/install-cni/843e7a92
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-flannel/a3934024
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-flannel/e4aa6627
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-flannel/3316e4ef
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-flannel/b3c0c65b
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-flannel/5520d34e
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-flannel/fc02f300
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-flannel/2b3ea969
/var/lib/kubelet/pods/478813b4-31b8-11e9-a4aa-000c295ecaec/containers/kube-flannel/c445f6e1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does not impose any security concern. 
Please note, that disclosed by you files in the listing (with 666 permissions) cannot be accessed unless parent directories in the path has the e**x**ecute bit permission set (ref. Linux [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)).